# Dragging doesn't work in Google Maps iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have the following method defined in a view controller class. At the last line of this code I declare the draggable attribute to be set to YES, but surprisingly it doesn't work when in the app.

What may cause this?

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
CLLocationDegrees latitude = -33.861;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = 151.20;
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
marker.map = _mapView;
marker.draggable = YES;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to long push the marker then you can drag it.